# Resize dock to height of visible contents

Tags: python, pyqt5, qlayout

I'm creating a collapsible widget.  It contains a table and is embedded in another widget beneath some group boxes.  Everything is put into a dock.  The table contained in the collapsible widget vertically fills the dock when the collapsible widget is expanded; the group boxes remain fixed.  However, the dock resizes to the height of the group boxes and the collapsible widget button *only if the dock hasn't been resized first*.

Notice how after resizing the dock, the dock remains the same size as the table which was collapsed:

[image]

How can I have the dock resize like on first load, to the minimum height of the group boxes and toggle button?  Or maybe a better question, how does the dock widget determine its minimum size and how can I advise it to be minimum size (if not through MinimumExpanding)?

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWidgets


class CollapsibleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text=title, checkable=True, checked=True)
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        self.toggle_button.pressed.connect(self.on_pressed)

        self.content_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.content_widget.setLayout(self.content_layout)
        self.content_widget.hide()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_widget)

    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.content_widget.setVisible(checked)


class ControlWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

        # Checkboxes
        self.checkbox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Checkbox1")
        self.checkbox2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Checkbox2")

        # Buttons
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')

        # Checkbox group
        self.gb_checkbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Checkboxes")
        self.layout_gb_checkbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_gb_checkbox.addWidget(self.checkbox1)
        self.layout_gb_checkbox.addWidget(self.checkbox2)
        self.gb_checkbox.setLayout(self.layout_gb_checkbox)
        self.gb_checkbox.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        # Button group
        self.gb_button = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Buttons")
        self.layout_gb_button = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button3)
        self.gb_button.setLayout(self.layout_gb_button)
        self.gb_button.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        # groups layout
        self.groups_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.groups_layout.addWidget(self.gb_checkbox)
        self.groups_layout.addWidget(self.gb_button)

        # table
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        for i in range(20):
            self.table.insertRow(i)

        # Collapsible widget
        self.collapsible_widget = CollapsibleWidget("Table")
        self.collapsible_widget.content_layout.addWidget(self.table)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setSpacing(0)
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addLayout(self.groups_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.collapsible_widget)

        self.setLayout(layout)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    controls = ControlWidget()

    # Dock
    dock_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
    dock_layout.setContentsMargins(4, 0, 4, 0)
    dock_layout.addWidget(controls)

    dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Control Panel")
    dock_contents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    dock_contents.setLayout(dock_layout)
    dock.setWidget(dock_contents)

    # central widget
    central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    central_widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: gray')

    # main window
    main_window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    main_window.resize(640, 480)
    main_window.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, dock)
    main_window.setCentralWidget(central_widget)

    main_window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I tried setting the sizeHint of the dock really low and setting sizePolicy on the dock to MinimumExpanding or Expanding.  I expected the dock to then try resizing to the minimum, but then resize to the minimum of its contents.  There was no noticeable change in behavior.

I tried accessing the dock within the on_pressed() call and forcing it to resize().  Again, no noticeable change in behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the layout of a QMainWindow (and the layout of the dock areas) is almost unaccessible, at least from python. The main problem is that dock widgets are added to an internal system of layouts that also keeps trace of manual resizing, and there's no way (at least, that I know of) to "reset" those sizes.

There exist some possible workarounds, though.

One idea is that the collapsible widget emits a signal whenever it's collapsed, and that signal is connected to a specialized function of the main window.

In this case, I'll automatically connect the signal whenever a dock widget is set as parent of the main window (but there are other ways to do so). Then the trick is to check whether the dock is floating or not, and then, respectively:

- resize it according to its *minimum* (vertical) size hint
- force the vertical sizing of the dock

```
class CollapsibleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    collapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    # ...
    def on_pressed(self):
        checked = self.toggle_button.isChecked()
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(
            QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if checked else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.content_widget.setVisible(checked)
        if not checked:
            self.collapsed.emit()


class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def childEvent(self, event):
        if event.added() and isinstance(event.child(), QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
            for resizable in event.child().findChildren(CollapsibleWidget):
                resizable.collapsed.connect(self.collapsibleResized)

    def collapsibleResized(self):
        widget = self.sender()
        dock = widget.parent()
        while not isinstance(dock, QtWidgets.QDockWidget):
            dock = dock.parent()
        if dock.isFloating():
            def delayedResize():
                dock.resize(dock.width(), dock.minimumSizeHint().height())
        else:
            def delayedResize():
                self.resizeDocks(
                    [dock], 
                    [dock.widget().minimumSizeHint().height()], 
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical
                )
        QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, delayedResize)
```

There could be some issues whenever multiple dock are added (or tabified), and I'm not sure about restoring dock state, so you should probably do some deep testing.

Comment: Thank you, yet again!  Is there a particular reason you connect the table through the `childEvent`?  I would expect to do it with something like `        self.controls.collapsible_widget.collapsed.connect(self.on_collapse)` within the MainWidget.  Is that what you meant by "but there are other ways to do so"?  Finally, am I correct in that the singleShot is used to account for the processing of events?

Comment: @LoremIpsum 1. Yes: I don't know what you're going to implement that, using the childEvent ensures that *any* new QDockWidget that has a collapsible widget will be automatically and correctly connected to the proper signal; note that, for coherence, you should also disconnect it in case you plan to remove (delete or reparent) dock widgets. 2. Yes, resizing often results in events requiring more cycles of the event loop, so you cannot execute it instantly: you must wait for the layout to correctly finish "its job".

Answer (score 0):

I'm satisfied with the following, based off of @musicamante's response.  The code is slightly improved from the question:

- Replaced fixed size policies on group boxes with a stretch on the collapsible widget; this makes the group boxes the same size
- Removed the spacing(0); this makes the group boxes not run into one another
- Updated on_pressed() to toggle_expanded(); allows programmatic use

Otherwise, through testing, the following works quite well.  Signals exist for "collapsed" and "expanded" state changes.  These are connected directly in the MainWindow.  When collapsing, the dock resizes according to the minimum height (per @musicamante).  The current dock height is saved before collapsing.  On expanding,  the last known dock height is restored.  Resizing is locked when collapsed to prevent any weird, intermediate states (where the dock extends beyond the table, as seen in the original question).

Testing with saving state and geometry, only the dock widget location and geometry itself is preserved.  Any state within the dock, such as whether the collapsible widget is expanded, must be handled separately after init.  Use toggle_expanded().

I tried various permutations of processing events, delay durations, and calling the delayed_resize() immediately.  All produced occasional flickers wherein the table expanded to something like 6 rows but immediately resized.  The flickering is irregular, occurs only during expansion, and is, as far as I can tell, a minor detail.  Occasionally, when switching between floating and docked, the height would reduce slightly.  This is appears to be because the height of the dock includes the title bar when floating.  The title bar is absent when docked.

There is an extra dock widget thrown in for good measure.  Everything sizes as expected.

```py
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets, QtWidgets


class CollapsibleWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    collapsed = QtCore.pyqtSignal()
    expanded = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, title="", parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName('CollapsibleWidget')

        self.toggle_button = QtWidgets.QToolButton(text=title, checkable=True, checked=False)
        self.toggle_button.setToolButtonStyle(QtCore.Qt.ToolButtonTextBesideIcon)
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.toggle_button.setStyleSheet("QToolButton { border: none; }")
        self.toggle_button.clicked.connect(self.toggle_expanded)

        self.content_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.content_layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.content_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.content_widget.setLayout(self.content_layout)
        self.content_widget.hide()

        lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        lay.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        lay.addWidget(self.toggle_button, alignment=QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)
        lay.addWidget(self.content_widget)

    def toggle_expanded(self, expanded=True):
        self.toggle_button.setArrowType(QtCore.Qt.DownArrow if expanded else QtCore.Qt.RightArrow)
        self.content_widget.setVisible(expanded)
        if not expanded:  # regardless of whether the state actually changed
            self.collapsed.emit()
        else:
            self.expanded.emit()


class ControlWidget(QtWidgets.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setObjectName("ControlWidget")

        # Checkboxes
        self.checkbox1 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Checkbox1")
        self.checkbox2 = QtWidgets.QCheckBox("Checkbox2")

        # Buttons
        self.button1 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button1')
        self.button2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button2')
        self.button3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton('Button3')

        # Checkbox group
        self.gb_checkbox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Checkboxes")
        self.layout_gb_checkbox = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_gb_checkbox.addWidget(self.checkbox1)
        self.layout_gb_checkbox.addWidget(self.checkbox2)
        self.gb_checkbox.setLayout(self.layout_gb_checkbox)

        # Button group
        self.gb_button = QtWidgets.QGroupBox("Buttons")
        self.layout_gb_button = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button1)
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button2)
        self.layout_gb_button.addWidget(self.button3)
        self.gb_button.setLayout(self.layout_gb_button)

        # groups layout
        self.groups_layout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout()
        self.groups_layout.addWidget(self.gb_checkbox)
        self.groups_layout.addWidget(self.gb_button)

        # table
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        for i in range(20):
            self.table.insertRow(i)

        # Collapsible widget
        self.collapsible_widget = CollapsibleWidget("Table")
        self.collapsible_widget.content_layout.addWidget(self.table)

        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        layout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        layout.addLayout(self.groups_layout)
        layout.addWidget(self.collapsible_widget, stretch=1)

        self.setLayout(layout)

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        # Controls
        self.controls = ControlWidget()
        self.controls.collapsible_widget.collapsed.connect(self.on_collapse)
        self.controls.collapsible_widget.expanded.connect(self.on_expand)

        # Dock
        self.dock_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.dock_layout.setContentsMargins(4, 0, 4, 0)
        self.dock_layout.addWidget(self.controls)

        self.dock_contents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.dock_contents.setLayout(self.dock_layout)
        # Don't allow resizing unless expanded; initial states is collapsed
        self.dock_contents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)

        self.dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Control Panel")
        self.dock.setWidget(self.dock_contents)
        self._dock_last_expanded_height = self.dock.minimumSizeHint().height()

        # Extra Dock
        self.extra_dock_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))
        self.extra_dock_layout.addWidget(QtWidgets.QLabel('Extra Dock'))

        self.extra_dock_contents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.extra_dock_contents.setLayout(self.extra_dock_layout)

        self.extra_dock = QtWidgets.QDockWidget("Extra dock")
        self.extra_dock.setWidget(self.extra_dock_contents)

        # Central widget
        self.central_widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.central_widget.setStyleSheet('background-color: gray')

        self.resize(640, 480)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.dock)
        self.addDockWidget(QtCore.Qt.TopDockWidgetArea, self.extra_dock)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.central_widget)

    def on_collapse(self):
        self._dock_last_expanded_height = self.dock.height()

        if self.dock.isFloating():
            def delayed_resize():
                self.dock.resize(self.dock.width(), self.dock.minimumSizeHint().height())

        else:
            def delayed_resize():
                self.resizeDocks(
                    [self.dock],
                    [self.dock.widget().minimumSizeHint().height()],
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical
                )
        # Don't allow resizing unless expanded
        self.dock_contents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        # QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, delayed_resize)
        delayed_resize()

    def on_expand(self):
        if self.dock.isFloating():
            def delayed_resize():
                self.dock.resize(self.dock.width(), self._dock_last_expanded_height)

        else:
            def delayed_resize():
                self.resizeDocks(
                    [self.dock],
                    [self._dock_last_expanded_height],
                    QtCore.Qt.Vertical
                )
        # Allow resizing when expanded
        self.dock_contents.setSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        # QtWidgets.QApplication.processEvents()
        # QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(0, delayed_resize)
        delayed_resize()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    main_window = MainWindow()
    main_window.show()

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: The flickering might be caused by multiple timers getting fired. I suggest you to add some simple print statements in the `delayed_resize` functions in order to check if that's the case. If it is, then you could create a persistent QTimer instead, then call its `disconnect()` in a try/except block and finally reconnect to the proper function and restart the timer: in this way, it will only called the "last time" it's actually required.

Comment: AFAIK, the `delayed_resize` is only being called once.  Thank you for the advice.

Comment: I checked your code a bit, I can only see some (occasional) flickering on collapsing. It might depend on different aspects, including platform (I'm on Linux). I'd suggest you to keep the QTimer for the `delayed_resize` anyway, as resizing often requires a certain amount of event cycles. Try increasing the interval a bit (5-10ms). Also, the resizing issue of the floating state indeed depends on the title bar (that's why I used the `minimumSizeHint` of the dock, not that of its widget). You can store the correct size by doing proper checks connecting to the `topLevelChanged` signal.